# Square matrix with identical row space and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Row space and column space of square matrix $A$ are the same. What does that mean?

I guess that means $A$ is symmetric or eigenvalues of $A$ are all different.

Are there other possibilities? What is the theorem for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't imply $A$ symmetric nor that all eigenvalues different. Easy to see when $A$ is invertible: then the row and column spaces are equal. But there are scores of non-symmetric invertible matrices, and you can easily choose them with repeated eigenvalues. For an extreme example of non-different eigenvalues, consider the identity $I_n$.

With the idea above you can get examples for all dimensions of the column/row space by putting a matrix as above in the upper left corner.

Comment: What are all the cases? Can singular value decomposition help to define all the cases?

Comment: I don't think the singular value decomposition is of much help: the unitaries are invertible, and the diagonal matrix will always have the same column and row space, regardless of what the original matrix had.